# Buffered Image padding not working

Tags: java, image, image-processing, padding, bufferedimage

I have a image of dimension `215*112`. I want to make it `215*142`.

Src Img:

[image: Src Image]

I used the following code:

```
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("src.png"));

    int h = 15;
    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight() + 2 * h, image.getType());

    Graphics g = newImage.getGraphics();

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight() + 2 * h);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, h, null);
    g.dispose();

    ImageIO.write(newImage, "png", new File("dest.png"));
```

I am getting following result:

[image: dest img]

Why the padding is also getting added to `x` direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the source you are giving has two transparent vertical bars on the left and right of the image
[Use this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvYK8.png)